# What is the collective noun for a group of ghouls?

Tags: world-of-darkness, terminology

I have several ghoul characters and I was wondering if a group of ghouls is called anything specifically. A group of Kindred is a coterie, a group of Sabbat is a pack, a group of mortals that are fed on is a herd. Is there a collective noun for ghouls? These would generally be a group that is not used for feeding purposes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### There's not one.

As depicted in the game, ghouls are discouraged by their vampire domitors from organizing or socializing in groups, lest it lead to rebellion of one form or another. The V20 book **Ghouls and Revenants** discusses all-ghoul campaigns but never uses anything more specific than "a group of ghouls" to describe the collection of PCs.

Comment: Thanks, that makes total sense. One of the domitor's friends played by someone else called them daylight guardians because they stopped a hunter. I thought that was pretty awesome.

Comment: They do have a very unusually permissive/kind master who uses them mostly to mathematically test things. Like they will work on the mathematical aspects of cleaning up the 'coding' for spells when it comes to timing, minimizing error rates, etc. Without of course knowing anything directly about thaumaturgy. They work in abstract mathematical concepts that the vampire can then use to create cleaner thaumaturgy with less chance of botching. He was a mathematician himself and can break things down like that into something quantifiable they can work on.  They have been called math nerds.

Answer (score 6):

There is no canonical answer, as the accepted one points out. But being a Vampire storytelller for over 15 years (both tabletop and LARP) back in the 1990's, I tried to make the link from my non-official sources to what I believe would best fit the jargon used by some clans. I hope it is sufficient and I will propose several here, together with the clans that would/could use them.

---

[Hack Slash Master](http://hackslashmaster.blogspot.com.br/2011/06/on-collective-nouns-for-fantasy.html) back in 2011 coined collectives for several "Fantasy" creatures (more like D&D, but still):

> **Ghoul** - A **rot** of ghouls

(but these are the undead ghouls of Dungeons & Dragons probably). Nosferatu probably would use this.

You can come up with other collectives too:

From [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary_of_collective_nouns_by_subject):

- [skulk](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/skulk) is used for thugs and thieves. Gangrel or Brujah.
- [pallor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pallor) is used for nightwatchmen / night students (probably those who study at night rather than those that study the night, but still).
- [obeisance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obeisance) is used for servants. A Toreador or Ventrue (even Tremere) could use this.

Comment: while excellent in itself, this is a question specific on WoD terminology. Drawing from other sources is ok only to some degree as the question isn't tagged [tag:World-of-Darkness] for no reason.

Comment: @Trish there is no canonical answer, as the accepted one points out. But being a Vampire storytelller for over 15 years (both tabletop and LARP) back in the 1990's, I tried to make the link from my non-official sources to what I believe would best fit the jargon used by some clans. Hope it is sufficient.

Comment: Adding this self reflection to the answer is the way to improve it then!

Comment: @Trish appreciated.